# TinyMCE not blank on start

Tags: tinymce

When my form submits I use this to copy the contents of tinymce to the text area it has replaced for validation purposes.

```
var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
$('#article').val(content);
```

The problem is, the content of the editor is the following on startup (although I see nothing in the editor):

```
<span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: 100;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,sans-serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: 100;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: 400;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,sans-serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: 400;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,serif; font-style: italic; font-weight: 600;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,sans-se...ont-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;">BESbswy</span><span style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px; font-size: 300px; width: auto; height: auto; line-height: normal; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-variant: normal; font-family: proxima-nova,sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;">BESbswy</span>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Your editor content is not visible due to its styling:

`top: -999px; left: -999px;` is outside the visible part of the editor iframe!